# DLL file handle changes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, libraries

I have been using the python ctypes library (in cygwin on windows 7) to make calls to a dll that was written in c and built on cygwin.
Recently, the producer of the dll put out an update and now the file handle changes every time I call ctypes.CDLL, the old version used to take the same handle each time.

My question is: What differences in the build process of a dll could cause it to take a consistent file handle each time vs taking a new one each time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The handle is just the virtual base address where the DLL was loaded.  DLLs can load at randomized addresses if a feature like [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows) (Address Space Layout Randomization) is enabled.

If the address chosen by ASLR is already occupied the loader can relocate it anywhere it likes.

Comment: Isn't the handle just an opaque structure pointer, that apps should never make assumptions about its value?

Comment: @ChristiFati Of course, but it is still OK to ask why and on Windows a DLL module handle *is* just the virtual base address it was loaded at :^)